Is it a Db9 with a #11 or a D with a b9 and a #11?
I don't know why I haven't gotten stuck on this before, but it being the season here I am playing Having Yourself a Merry Little Christmas with the 4th measure transitioning D-7 to Db9#11 to Cmaj7, and I'm stuck.
Is the middle chord a Db with a 9 and a #11, or is it a D with a b9 and a #11? And how would I tell the difference?
To my ear they both sound pretty wacky, so that's no help. I'll be the first to admit I don't have much of an ear.

It’s a Db root for sure but it would be good to see a pic of what you’re reading because sometimes the chord symbols themselves give you hints or clues to help distinguish between the two things you thought it might be.

Are you asking what the notes are or, given the notes, what the chord is named?

It's Db(9)(#11). It's what's known as a tritone substitution (The Db chord substituting for a G7 chord) and is used to create a smooth bass line from, in this case, D to C.
For more, see What is tritone substitution?
The difference between D(b9)(#11) would ordinarily be made clear by the way the chord symbol is typeset. As one example:

Db9#11
Db9#11

Other indications are

The context. In this case the transition from D-7 to CM7 making it fairly clear once one is familiar enough with tritone substitution.
Convention. A (9#11) chord is fairly common, but a triad with an added b9 and #11 (that is, no 7th in the chord) is somewhat unusual.
The notation itself. Db9#11 is understood as shorthand for Db7(9)(#11), and Db7 would never mean a D major triad with a flat seven added — that would be D7, which would not be written D(b7).


I think a more common notation for D(b9)(#11) would be D7b9#11

@user1079505 The chord as written would contain no 7th degree so there is a difference between the two.
